# Multidimensional array loop error

Tags: javascript, for-loop, multidimensional-array, while-loop

I'm trying to loop through the columns, using a while loop but every time I'm getting an error and I was wondering if you guys can tell me what I did wrong.
the code is this:

```
var arr = [
    [['cat', 'fish'],['dog', 'meat']],
    [['cat', 'toy'],['dog', 'bone']],
    [['cat', 'fish'],['dog', 'bone']]
];

var position = 0;
//can I do this in stead?
//while(arr.length > position){

while(true){
  var arrEnd = true;
  for (var k = 0; k < arr.length; k++) {
    if(arr.length > position){
      arrEnd = false;
    }
  }

  if(arrEnd){break;}

  for(var i =0; i < arr.length;i++){
    for(var j =0; j < arr.length;j++){
      if(i != j && arr[i][position][1] == arr[j][position][1]){
        console.log(arr[i][position]+'===='+arr[j][position]);
      }
    }
  }
  position++;
}
//Expected:
// "cat,fish====cat,fish" "cat,fish====cat,fish"
// "dog, bone====dog,bone" "dog, bone====dog,bone"
//Error getting: arr[i][position] is undefined
```

What is wrong? I can't see the issue.

Comment: Why do you go through the same array 3 times?

Comment: can u tell us what you want to accomplish or what is your desired result at the end?

Comment: @GopinathShiva I add what I was expecting.

Comment: You can check yourself what went wrong by visualizing your javascript code one step after another over here - http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit

Comment: @smnbbrv the first is to go out of the loop.

Comment: The value of `arr.length` is 3, because you have 3 rows. But you have 2 columns. You use the rows length as index to columns.

I'm sorry about my english...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a three dimensional array. You are originally using `position` against the first index of the array, then later, where the error occurs, you use `position` to reference the second index. Since the first dimension is longer than the second dimension, you eventually get an error as a result of the value at the requested index not being defined.

Assuming that the inner arrays are of equal length at each level, this works:

```
var arr = [
    [['cat', 'fish'],['dog', 'meat']],
    [['cat', 'toy'],['dog', 'bone']],
    [['cat', 'fish'],['dog', 'bone']]
];

var position = 0;
while(true){
  var arrEnd = true;
  for (var k = 0; k < arr[0].length; k++) {
    if(arr[0].length > position){
      arrEnd = false;
    }
  }

  if(arrEnd){break;}

  for(var i =0; i < arr.length;i++){
    for(var j =0; j < arr.length;j++){
      if(i != j && arr[i][position][1] == arr[j][position][1]){
        console.log(arr[i][position]+'===='+arr[j][position]);
      }
    }
  }
  position++;
}
```

Note the additional `[0]`s in the first `for` loop.

Though, really, the code should be rearranged to be more clear as to what's going on so as to make issues like this easier to see:

```
var arr = [
    [['cat', 'fish'],['dog', 'meat']],
    [['cat', 'toy'],['dog', 'bone']],
    [['cat', 'fish'],['dog', 'bone']]
];

for(var i=0; i < arr.length-1; i++){
  for(var j=i+1; j < arr.length; j++){
    for(var k=0; k < arr[i].length; k++){
      if(arr[i][k][1] == arr[j][k][1]) {
        console.log(arr[i][k]+'===='+arr[j][k]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with `while (true)` and `position++` outside of `for`. Eventually, `position` will be greater than 1, causing the exact error you're receiving.

One more thing to note, your `arr` has length of 3, while max position number (second dimension index) would be 1 (since you have 2 arrays in your subarray).

Instead of your nested `for` loop, try using [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/Obiekty/Array/forEach).